# Invoking a rest api client

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven, restclientbuilder

I have created a rest api in eclipse as a maven project.
MobileAnalyticsModel class for rest api is

```
package org.subhayya.amazonws.mobileanalytics;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class MobileAnalyticsModel {

    private String name;
    private Date created;
    private String location;
    private String prize;
    private String requirement;

    public MobileAnalyticsModel() {

    }
    public MobileAnalyticsModel(String name, String location, String prize, String requirement) {

        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.prize = prize;
        this.requirement = requirement;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getPrize() {
        return prize;
    }

    public void setPrize(String prize) {
        this.prize = prize;
    }

    public String getRequirement() {
        return requirement;
    }

    public void setRequirement(String requirement) {
        this.requirement = requirement;
    }
}
```

this is the json response of the created api:

[image: this is the json response of the created api]

and
this is my sample test code for invoking rest api:

```
package org.subhayya.example;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class SampleTestREstClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( );
        String reponse = client.target("http://localhost:8080/AgentBasedCloudServiceCompositionFramework/webapi/mobileanalytics/mobileanalyticsjson")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(String.class);

        System.out.println(reponse);
    }}
```

then i got full json response.. as

```
 [{"created":"2017-03-30T14:36:58.56","location":"http://api.server.com","name":"Mobile Analytics","prize":"$1.00 per 1,000,000 Amazon Mobile Analytics events per month thereafter","requirement":"PutEvents"}]
```

But I want to have the single parameter as my output, for e.g., name, location or requirement.I am creating client invoking code also in the same maven project. So I wrote my code as below

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( );
MobileAnalyticsModel reponse = 
        client.target("http://localhost:8080/AgentBasedCloudServiceCompositionFramework/webapi/mobileanalytics/mobileanalyticsjson")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get(MobileAnalyticsModel.class);

System.out.println(reponse.getName());
```

But I am getting exception, So I changed it to `System.out.println(reponse);`
) get atleast JSON response, then also getting error.

[image: console view]

how do I get single name parameter from the JSON response? I am new to this rest api..please help me to fix this as soon as possible.thanks in advance

Comment: Please include MobileAnalyticsModel class code in your question

Comment: And which exception do you get? Did you try RESTEasy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check the below link to convert json to object.

[Parse a JSON response as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808018/parse-a-json-response-as-an-object)

Answer (score 2):

Your response is a string. The simplest way to access elements of your JSON-response is to convert the resonse to a Json-Object. Then you can access the fields easily by their name.
Have a look at:
[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me..

```
 String url = "http://localhost:8080/AgentBasedCloudServiceCompositionFramework/webapi/mobileanalytics/";
            String city = "mobileanalyticsjson";
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget webTarget = client.register(JsonProcessingFeature.class).target(url);
            JsonArray jsonArray = webTarget.path(city)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(JsonArray.class);
            for (JsonObject jsonObject : jsonArray.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)) {
                   System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name")); 
                   System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("location")); }
```